Distribute the scores dynamically in Python (Pandas)
I have the following pandas DF,
ID       value1          value2
1          90             1000
2          89              999
3          89              998
4          85             1000
5          84              850

I have a list,
score = [6,7,8,9,10]

I want to dynamically segregate the IDs by evenly distributing them to the scores in the list. This should be based on the decreasing order of value1 and value2 column.
The output should be as follows,
ID       value1          value2     score
1          90             1000        10
2          89              999         9
3          89              998         8
4          85             1000         7
5          84              850         6

If the input is as follows,
ID       value1          value2
1          90             1000
2          89              999
3          89              998
4          85             1000
5          84              850
6          83              998
7          82             1000
8          81              850

the output should be,
ID       value1          value2         score
1          90             1000            10
2          89              999            10
3          89              998             9
4          85             1000             9
5          84              850             8
6          83              998             8
7          82             1000             7
8          81              850             6

If the input is as follows,
ID       value1          value2
1          90             1000
2          89              999
3          89              998
4          85             1000
5          84              850
6          83              998
7          82             1000
8          81              850
9          80              998
10         79             1000
11         78              850

the output should be,
ID       value1          value2        score
1          90             1000           10
2          89              999           10
3          89              998           10 
4          85             1000            9
5          84              850            9
6          83              998            8
7          82             1000            8
8          81              850            7
9          80              998            7
10         79             1000            6
11         78              850            6

Any help would be appreciated.

What determines the value computed for the score column?

@itprorh66 I sort the df by value1 and value2 in descending order and the evenly distribute score column based on the list in the score list.

so you are randomly distributing the values in score to an ID? There is no determining condition that is being applied?

the condition is that we sort it by value1 and value2 in descending order. if the length of the df is 10 and length of the score list is 5, I want each score to have 2 IDs assigned based on the value1 and value2 order. if the length of the df is 15 and length of the score list is 5, I want each score to have 3 IDs assigned based on the value1 and value2 order.

You could write a function that gives the score_values:
import numpy as np

def score_values(score, n):
   a = np.tile(score[::-1], n//len(score)+1)[:n]
   return a[(-a).argsort()]

Now use this to get the score:
score = [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

score_values(score, 5)
array([10,  9,  8,  7,  6])


score_values(score, 8)
array([10, 10,  9,  9,  8,  8,  7,  6])


score_values(score, 11)
array([10, 10, 10,  9,  9,  8,  8,  7,  7,  6,  6])

